# c++ classes with swig to python module

Tags: python, c++, swig

I need to convert this class of c ++ to a python module and gives errors
/* arexcrypt.h*/

```
#ifndef AREXCRYPT_H
#define AREXCRYPT_H

//Qt
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <QFlags>
//App
#include "singleton.h"

class ArexCrypt: public Singleton<ArexCrypt>
{
friend class Singleton<ArexCrypt>;

public:
enum Compression {
    IfReducedCompress,
    AlwaysCompress,
    NeverCompress
};
enum IntegrityCheck {
    NoCheck,
    ChecksumCheck,
    HashCheck
};
enum Error {
    NoneError,
    NoKeyError,
    NoDataError,
    UnknownVersionError,
    IntegrityError
};
enum CryptoFlag{
    NoneFlag = 0,
    CompressedFlag = 0x01,
    ChecksumFlag = 0x02,
    HashFlag = 0x04
};

Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(CryptoFlags, CryptoFlag);

void setKey(quint64 pKey);
Compression CompressionMode() const;
void setCompressionMode(Compression pMode);
IntegrityCheck IntegrityProtectionMode() const;
void setIntegrityProtectionMode(IntegrityCheck pMode);
Error LastError() const;

//METHODS
QString EncryptToString(const QString &pText);
QString DecryptToString(const QString &pEncryptedText);
QString GenerateIntegrityKey(const QString &pText);
bool CheckIntegrityKey(const QString &pText);

private:
//Data
quint64 key;
QVector<char> keyParts;
Compression compressionMode;
IntegrityCheck protectionMode;
Error lastError;
bool showConsoleMessages;

//CONTRUCTORS AND DESTROYERS
ArexCrypt();

//METHODS
void SplitKey();
void EncryptArray(QByteArray &pArray);
void DecryptArray(QByteArray &pArray);
QByteArray GenerateIntegrityData(QByteArray dataArray, CryptoFlags &flags);
QByteArray EncryptToByteArray(QByteArray pTextArray);
QByteArray DecryptToByteArray(QByteArray pEncryptedArray);
//OTHERS
QString EncryptToString(QByteArray pTextArray);
QString DecryptToString(QByteArray pEncryptedArray);
QByteArray EncryptToByteArray(const QString &pText);
QByteArray DecryptToByteArray(const QString &pEncryptedText);
};

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(ArexCrypt::CryptoFlags);

#endif // AREXCRYPT_H
```

/*arexcrypt.i*/

```
/* arexcrypt.i */
%module arexcrypt
%{
#include "arexcrypt.h"
%}

%import "singleton.i"
%include std_string.i
%include std_vector.i
%include stl.i
%include "arexcrypt.h"
```

/* singleton.h */

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template <typename T> struct Singleton
{
    static T &instance()
    {
        static T m_instance;
        return m_instance;
    }
protected:
    Singleton() { }
};

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

/* singleton.i */

```
/* singleton.i */
%module singleton
%{
#include "singleton.h"
%}

%include "singleton.h"
%template(intSingleton) Singleton<int>;
```

then when I convert to python I get this on the console

> > swig -c++ -python arexcrypt.i

arexcrypt.h(11) : Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'Singleton< ArexCrypt >'. Ignored.
arexcrypt.h(11) : Warning 401: Maybe you forgot to instantiate 'Singleton< ArexCrypt >' using %template.
arexcrypt.h(40) : Warning 504: Function ArexCrypt::Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(CryptoFlags,ArexCrypt::CryptoFlag) must have a return type. Ignored.
arexcrypt.h(81) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'ArexCrypt::CryptoFlags' unless renamed to a valid identifier.

> > gcc -c arexcrypt_wrap.cxx -o arexcrypt.o -fpic -std=c++0x

i get this

```
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:1: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent)
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:171:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:3027:4: error: #error "This python version requires swig to be run with the '-classic' option"
In file included from arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:3124:
arexcrypt.h:5:19: error: QString: No such file or directory
arexcrypt.h:6:19: error: QVector: No such file or directory
arexcrypt.h:7:18: error: QFlags: No such file or directory
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:801: error: 'PyObject' was not declared in this scope
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:801: error: 'str' was not declared in this scope
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:802: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:825: error: expected initializer before '*' token
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:851: error: expected initializer before '*' token
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:905: error: expected initializer before '*' token
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:920: error: 'inquiry' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:921: error: 'intargfunc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:922: error: 'intintargfunc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:923: error: 'intobjargproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:924: error: 'intintobjargproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:925: error: 'getreadbufferproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:926: error: 'getwritebufferproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:927: error: 'getsegcountproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:928: error: 'getcharbufferproc' does not name a type
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:929: error: 'PyObject' was not declared in this scope
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:929: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:929: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:929: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:930: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
In file included from c:\mingw64_4.4.6\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.4.6/stdexcept:38,
                 from arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:3051:
c:\mingw64_4.4.6\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.4.6/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line
```

anyone know what might be going I'm doing wrong

Comment: sorry I missed things

Comment: /*#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template <typename T> struct Singleton
{
 static T &instance()
 {
  static T m_instance;
  return m_instance;
 }
protected:
 Singleton() { }
};

#endif // SINGLETON_H*/

Answer (score 0):

as a rule: always look at the *first* error - that is likely your culprit.

In your case

```
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:1: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent)
arexcrypt_wrap.cxx:171:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

You're missing the python development files.